# UITableView with Parse objects

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I am new using Parse with iOS. I am creating a UITableView that should be populated with Parse objects. This are the methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void) retrieveFromParse {

    PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"cadenas"];

    [retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            colorsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"descargado=%@",colorsArray);
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

The previous NSLog shows the two existing Parse objects.

And now the table view methods:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    // Usually the number of items in your array (the one that holds your list)
    return [colorsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Where we configure the cell in each row

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
     PFObject *tempObject = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"CADNA =%@:",[colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"chain_name"];;
    return cell;

}
```

The last NSLog is not called, and therefor, the UITableView is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: did you set the delegate and datasource of the tableView?

Comment: @YuviGr, yes I did. I have tested it with a NSArray, and the array items are shown. Thank you.

Comment: where is colorsArray declared?

Comment: @YuviGr, it is declared in the h. file, as NSArray.

Comment: set a breakpoint in the numberOfRowsInSection: method. Check if the count is 0

Comment: @YuviGr, ok. I will tell you

Comment: @YuviGr, the count is 0.

Comment: make sure property is (strong)

Comment: @MishaVyrko, do you mean the table view? It is strong  declared.

Comment: One unusual thing in the code is the performSelector in viewDidLoad.  The zero you're seeing may be because the datasource gets called (starting in iOS8, I think) while the view is being built.  Please add a viewDidAppear override, call super viewDidAppear there, then call (not perform) your retrieveFromParse method.

Comment: check to see that the colorsArray is not nil once you set it

Comment: is colorsArray declared as a property?  
If so you should be using self.colorsArray instead, which would mean colorsArray is nil when [colorsArray count] is called.  
Since asking the count of nil in obj-C returns zero, it would mean your tableview has zero entries and would never enter cellForRowAtIndexPath.   
Just a theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the [ParseUI repository](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS) which provides commonly used Cocoa Touch classes that fetches data from parse.

If you do end up using it, all you need to implement are these methods :

- `(PFQuery *)queryForTable`
- `(UITableViewCell *)tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: object:`
- And other wanted `UITableViewDelegate` methods

When you want to update the tableView, simply call `[self loadObjects];`

Here is a sample class that will work ([taken from the ParseUI repo demo](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUIDemo/Classes/CustomViewControllers/QueryTableViewController/StoryboardTableViewController.m)):

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>

@interface StoryboardTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController

@end
```

And the implementation :

```
#import "StoryboardTableViewController.h"

#import <Parse/PFObject.h>
#import <Parse/PFQuery.h>

#import <ParseUI/PFTableViewCell.h>

@implementation StoryboardTableViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Data

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [super queryForTable];
    [query orderByAscending:@"priority"];
    return query;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TableView

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Priority: %@", object[@"priority"]];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is query timing vs. building the view.  Rather than...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // remove this
    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];
```

... do this...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self retrieveFromParse];
}
```

This way, we know deterministically that all the views are built and ready after the find completes.

Comment: No success with your proposal. Same result, NSLog(@"descargado=%@",colorsArray); is called after numberOfRowsInSection...  ??

Comment: It's called after, but then we should see the datasource called again on the reload.  That would indicate an even simpler problem, that the self.tableView outlet is not set.  Just before calling reload, NSLog(@"%@", self.tableView);.  I think my suggestion in the answer is still advisable, but maybe the problem is very simple.

Comment: Thank you Danh, no success either. But I will try using a PFQueryTableViewController, may be this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is the method "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" running in a separate thread?
If so, you might be calling [self.tableView reloadData] in a thread other than the main thread, which is not really a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, understood, but then where do I reload the table view?

Comment: I have put a NSLog at the numberOfRowsInSection method, and the output of this NSLog appears first, then the NSLog from the viewDidLoad method, that should mean that the table view is populated before the data are received from Parse, right?

Comment: @mvasco - this idea is well-meaning, but not useful.  The block runs on the main and your code to update the table is correctly placed.

Comment: You can try something like that:
`[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                 withObject:nil
                              waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: @mvasco Yeah, i thought so after seeing the other comments about it running in the main thread